# javascript inside php and inside that javascript php code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have scenario that I want javascript inside php code and in this javascript I want to execute php code for execute mysql query.

On my submit button I have call javascript so I can't call ajax for checking value from database so I have put code in submit button function.

I need functionality if user confirm then mysql update query will execute but if user not confirm then it will goes to accountlist.php page

```
         if (isset($_POST['createcomapny']) && $_POST['createcomapny'] == "Submit") {
              $company = $_POST['cmpname'];
              $user = $_POST['username'];
              $checkquery = mysql_query("select * from license_info where company_name='$company' and admin_user_name='$user'");

              if($checkrecord>0){
                      echo "<script>var conf=confirm('Are you sure want to create this company'); if(conf){";
                      mysql_query("update license_info set admin_user_name='lalu' where company_name='$company' and admin_user_name='$user'");
                      echo "} else { windows.location='accountlist.php';  }</script>";
        }
```

On submit button I have check javascript validation.

```
function create()
            {
                if (document.companyregister.cmpname.value === "")
                {
                    alert("Please Enter Company name");
                    document.companyregister.cmpname.value = "";
                    document.companyregister.cmpname.focus();
                    return false;
                }
                var company = document.companyregister.cmpname.value;
                var user = document.companyregister.user.value;
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();                    
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {            
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {                    
                var res = xmlhttp.responseText;                    
                var resu = res.split("|");                    
                if(resu[0]=="lokesh"){                        
                      document.getElementById('selectdriver1').style.display = 'block';                                                
                      document.getElementById("drvr").style.display = "none";
                      document.getElementById('findprinter').disabled = false;
                }                                        
                document.getElementById('driver').innerHTML = resu[1];
                return false;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "getaccount.php?", true);
            xmlhttp.send();                                        
            return true;

            document.getElementById("formsubmitting").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("hidesubmit").style.display = "none";
            return true;
            }
```

Comment: You seem a little confused about the separation of client and server side code, so I would suggest you research that subject. With regard to your question, to do what you require you will have to use AJAX.

Comment: But if I call ajax then before ajax action complete code page get true value because of asynchronous call.

Comment: This is why you need to use the callback of the AJAX request

Comment: I will edit question and show you problem that I am facing currently.

Answer (score -1):

Just use form with method="POST". If user confirms, set value of input named "confirm" true in javascript and send form. You can add all data you need as hidden inputs.

Javascript to submit it:

```
if(conf){ document.getElementById("myForm").submit(); }
```

PHP:

```
if($_POST['confirm']==true) { do action }
```

Btw. Can't you popup this message to confirm before sending a form? Basically you will send 2 times form like that. You can just add confirmation before sending first one...

Comment: You did not understand my problem. I want confirm in javascript after submit button is clicked and in action of submit button in need javascript.

Comment: Well, I did understand problem. The only solution to not refresh page again is use AJAX. You said you cannot use AJAX. So just send another form with additional confirm data :)

It is not possible to put PHP code inside JavaScript.

And you said you cannot use AJAX and you're actually using it after edit. I am confused.